# How do I correctly reference Users in GQL queries on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a db.Model that has a db.UserProperty.  For example:

```
class Photo( db.Model ):
    owner = db.UserProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
```

When I want to get all the photos for a user, I do this:

```
photos = Photo.gql( "WHERE owner = USER(:1)", users.get_current_user().nickname() )
```

This is causing problems, however, between Google and non-Google nicknames.  When testing locally, if I use the email address test@example.com, then the nickname is "test@example.com".  If I use test@gmail.com, then the nickname is "test".  When I test with a Gmail account, I have to append "@gmail.com" to .nickname().

Is there a better way to do this than hard-coding + "@gmail.com" to all my database queries?

Comment: Nicknames aren't guaranteed (or even intended) to be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`photos = Photo.gql("WHERE owner = :1", users.get_current_user())`

Comment: Well, that was simple!  Thanks!

Comment: Also if you are getting the value from html, then you should create a user object by passing username to Users.User().